# Why use JQuery element creation syntax?

Tags: jquery, html, syntax

JQuery element creation syntax is as follows:

```
var myDiv = $('<div>', {
    id   : "myDiv1",
    html : "Hello World!"
});
```

Standard HTML string creation syntax, which can also be used by JQuery, is as follows:

```
var myDiv = "<div id='myDiv1'>Hello World!</div>";
```

What are the benefits, if any, of using the JQuery element creation syntax?

EDIT: I **don't** want opinions. I want **real** reasons as to why one is preferable or why there is no difference. I think it is important to use consistent syntax across a project, so it is necessary to know reasons behind choosing one over the other. If there is no difference, we can use whichever one the most people are comfortable. This is not an opinion based question.

Comment: It is a personal opinion. It is just a way to make an element. Some people will say "It is great because it is compact." Others will Say, "BUT it requires so much code."

Comment: It really seems like there must be more to it than that- hence the question. If that is the answer I get and it is generally agreed upon, though, I will readily accept it.

Comment: Make your own JSPerf and see what the speed difference is. It is just a way to make an element. Do you want to build a huge string and worry about quotes or do you want to set an object with the pieces. It is what you prefer.

Comment: Because it allows you to bind event handlers etc.. right up front

Comment: The first option is more "object-oriented", it's awesome for:

1. An important application element: for **further maintence**
2. A lot usage of parametes: for readability

The second option, is a quick and traditional way to write HMTL, is good for:

1. minor importance element
2. little usage of parameter

Always remember: Keep it simple!, so as your example `<div id='myDiv1'>Hello World!</div>` is very easy to read and understand, in my opinion, second way is the best for this.

Actually using the 1st option for a small element is worse to read and understand than 2nd way.

Comment: Please post my comment as an answer, it's not opinion based.

Comment: @hackNightly Because you can't do `$("<div>foo</div>").on("click",function(){});`? Basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily substitute attribute values with variables without using string concatenation.

Comment: still opinion based... cause if you're inside a loop, I still think it's better to use the string concatenation...

Comment: Of course it's opinion-based; you can think whatever you want. But since you can easily extend a map of default properties, and it keeps things very compact when there are many attributes. Personally, I'll generally use templates over either technique, but there are use cases where the object version is *significantly* cleaner.

Comment: +1 Because the statement is not an opinion (even if not relevant in the shown case); the 2nd form *requires* string concatenation/building for dynamic values .. and any required escaping with string concatenation must be handled manually.